# Does iOS11 support WPS (WiFi Protected Setup)?

Tags: ios11, wps

I am trying to establish a wifi connection between iPhone and another ARM device(as AP), and thanks to NEHotsportConfiguration added in iOS11, the connecting process becomes easy and quick and all I need is AP's ssid and password which will be transmitted via BLE, Of cause they must be encrypted. now here comes the question if it's possible to use WPS instead of transmitting password in air.
I have read something and given my own answer No, so please correct me if have any mistakes, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  No version of iOS or OS X supports WPS because it has fundamental security flaws that cannot be readily fixed.  More to the point, you should disable WPS on any router that does support it, because it is a security hole so big you can drive a truck through it.

For more information, see:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/is-it-possible-to-connect-an-iphone-ipad-via-wifi-protected-setup-wps

and

http://routersecurity.org/wps.php